# How to escape quotes when importing csv file in PostgreSQL / YugabyteDB

Tags: postgresql, yugabytedb

Using YugabyteDB 2.5.3.1 (PostgreSQL 11.2).

I currently have this table:

```sql
create table bum2(id int, the_t text);
```

Looking to import this `"a"bc"` from a csv file into the text column.

Tried with this csv file:

```
6,""a""bc""
```

And:

```
\copy bum2 from data.csv WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

And getting:

```
yugabyte=# select * from bum2;
 id | the_t 
----+-------
  6 | abc
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional quotes to escape the quotes. The csv file below works:

```
6,"""a""bc"""
```

```
yugabyte=# \copy bum2 from data.csv WITH (FORMAT csv);
COPY 1
yugabyte=# select * from bum2;
 id | the_t  
----+--------
  6 | "a"bc"
(1 row)
```